# Commands fail with “<command> not found”, when executed using SSH.NET CreateCommand in C#

Tags: c#, .net, shell, ssh, ssh.net

I was trying to use the [SSH.NET NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET) to remotely execute a command to grab an app version that is installed on one iPhone connected to a Mac.

If executed on the Mac itself with below command, will get me its version:

```
ideviceinstaller -l|grep <bundleIdOfMyAppPackage>
```

So I build a small utility in C# with this package, hoping that I would leverage it. However, all I get is just an empty string. Would anyone let me know what I could do to get the result I want ? Thank you !

```
var host = "myhost";
var username = "username";
var password = "password";

using (var client = new SshClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.HostKeyReceived += delegate(object sender, HostKeyEventArgs e) { e.CanTrust = true; };

    client.Connect();
    var command = client.CreateCommand("ideviceinstaller -l|grep <bundleIdOfMyAppPackage>");
    command.Execute();

    var result = command.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

The error that I've got from `command.Error` is

> zsh1: command not found ideviceinstaller`

which is weird because I can see `ideviceinstaller` inside that folder if I browse to there.

---

I've got it working thanks to @Martin Prikryl by changing the command to:

```
/usr/local/bin/ideviceinstaller -l|grep <myAppBundleId>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSH.NET `SshClient.CreateCommand` (or `SshClient.RunCommand`) does not run shell in "login" mode and does not allocate a pseudo terminal for the session. As a consequence a different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced (particularly for non-interactive sessions, `.bash_profile` is not sourced), than in your regular interactive SSH session. And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on an absence/presence of `TERM` environment variable.

Possible solutions (in preference order):

1. Fix the command not to rely on a specific environment. Use a full path to `ideviceinstaller` in the command. E.g.:

   ```
    /path/to/ideviceinstaller ...
   ```

   If you do not know the full path, on common *nix systems, you can use `which ideviceinstaller` command in your interactive SSH session.
2. Fix your startup scripts to set the `PATH` the same for both interactive and non-interactive sessions.
3. Try running the script explicitly via login shell (use `--login` switch with common *nix shells):

   ```
    bash --login -c "ideviceinstaller ..."
   ```
4. If the command itself relies on a specific environment setup and you cannot fix the startup scripts, you can change the environment in the command itself. Syntax for that depends on the remote system and/or the shell. In common *nix systems, this works:

   ```
    PATH="$PATH;/path/to/ideviceinstaller" && ideviceinstaller ...
   ```
5. Another (not recommended) is to use "shell" channel to execute the command via `SshClient.CreateShellStream` or `SshClient.CreateShell` as these allocate pseudo terminal

   ```
    ShellStream shellStream = client.CreateShellStream(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    shellStream.Write("ideviceinstaller\n");

    while (true)
    {
        string s = shellStream.Read();
        Console.Write(s);
    }
   ```

   Using the shell and pseudo terminal to automate a command execution can bring you nasty side effects.

Comment: awesome !!! I've got it working. Thanks. I'll update my question